# How to cancel AsyncTask or all AsyncTask including nested AsyncTasks from same Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have **activity** use **AsyncTask to open cursor** than spawns **children AsyncTask to render items** read with cursor.

Activity executes on **cursor AsyncTask** but not see **children AsyncTask** for items.

How to cancel all running AsyncTask tasks (including nested) for specified Activity?

How to cancel all running children AsyncTask tasks for specified AsyncTask (if it possible at all)?

I want to stop all tasks on new command from interface to not corrupt views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no manager for the AsyncTask you execute.

You'll have to keep track of all the new instances of the AsyncTasks you've created and close them with `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` method.
Pay attention that canceling the Task won't stop it in the middle. You'll have to check in your `doInBackground` - `isCanceled()`

Comment: Good suggestion - it looks that I have to manage tasks. Some extra question if AsyncTasks onPostExecute will be executed in order as tasks is spawned or it need be managed in Android?

Comment: The onPostExecute is spawned right after the doInBackground finishes (unless the task is being canceled and then it won't spawn at all). So the answer is no - there's no order.

Comment: Thanks so it works as normal threading good to hear - I will accept answer.

Comment: I have just found that from HONEYCOMB default behaviour is changed since it is executing in one thread if not enable more. See (SERIAL_EXECUTOR and THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) not sure if it gives order but could.

Answer (score 0):

If your AsyncTask are running loops, then you can check for a common flag (maybe an attribute of some singleton, like the Application class itself, or your activity). As soon as this flag becomes true, then your Tasks will exit the loop